# mongoose setting referenceone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

Hello can someone help me. I can't set mongoose model field

Here my institute.js model file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var instituteSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    idApi: {type: String, required: true},
    country: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Country'
    },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, {collection: 'qel_par_institute', versionKey: false});

instituteSchema.methods.findByIdApi = function (id, callback) {
    return mongoose.model('Institute').findOne().where('idApi').equals(id).exec(callback);
}

instituteSchema.methods.findByCountry = function (id, callback) {
    return mongoose.model('Institute').find().where('country.id').equals(id).exec(callback);
}

mongoose.model('Institute', instituteSchema);
```

There the part of sync.js Persisting works except i can't either manually set the country ref neither another field

```
var instituteApi = new instituteModel({
    name: item.name,
    idFromApi: item.id
});
if (typeof item.country.id !== 'undefined') {
    var country = new countryModel();
    country.findByIdApi(item.country.id, function(err, res) {
        if (err) 
            console.log(err);

        if (res) {
            instituteApi.country = res._id; //setting this way doesn't work
        }
    })
}
instituteApi.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log('something went wrong while saving!');
});
```

Comment: oops got :  the global variable instituteApi is not defined in sync.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't set it because async call. Switched callback to promise with [Q module](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Everything works as wanted